# Kivy - Errant Vertical Splitter

Tags: python, kivy

I am attempting to construct a screen with a VERTICAL splitter to separate content; however, I am unsuccessful in identifying a solution even after consulting the kivy docs and looking through the related questions here.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.splitter import Splitter
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, DictProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

kv = '''

ScreenManagement:
    id: 'manager'
    MainScreen:
        name: 'main'
        manager: 'manager'

<MainScreen>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Button:
            text: 'New'

        Splitter:
            sizeable_from: 'top'
            Button:
                text: 'test'


'''


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):

    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):

    pass

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


MyApp().run()
```

Here is what I am current seeing with this code

[image]

As you can see, the splitter is beside the second button rather than between the buttons horizontally; and when the splitter is activated, it shrinks the button horizontally rather than vertically. How do I change the code for the effect that I desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple misspelling. `sizeable_from` should be `sizable_from`.